# Anomaly detection for multiple correlated variables (sensors)

Tags: time-series, anomaly-detection, cross-correlation

I have time series data from multiple sensors detecting vehicles driving through the sensor zone. I'm aggregating the total actuations for each sensor in 15-minute bins. The sensors are correlated, total actuations rise and fall together over the course of the day.

I'm using standard deviation for each sensor for a given hour of the day over past month to detect anomalies for each sensor but this doesn't work well if there are too many anomalies. Is there a way I can compare total actuations across the correlated sensors?

I'm doing this in SQL and Power Bi.
Thanks!

Comment: In what way does it not work well? If you are looking at each sensor independently that they are correlated across should not matter?

Comment: Are you looking to detect anomalies for the entire group of sensors, or for each sensor/vehicle?

Comment: Sometimes a sensor will show very high erratic counts or very low counts and this is affecting the the mean/standard deviation such that some of the anomalies are still within 3 standard deviations. I think this problem may be solved by using inter quartile range instead.

Comment: I want to detect anomalies for individual sensors. Because they are correlated I'm thinking a more robust solution would incorporate that.

Comment: Yes one should use a robust measure. Such as a percentile, or median absolute deviation (MAD)